# JOINing databases with SQLite

Tags: r, database, sqlite

I have 4 databases relating to the America's Cup.

```
SELECT * FROM teams
>
Code | Country                  | TeamName
ITA  |Italy                     | Luna Rossa Prada Pirelli Team     
NZ   |New Zealand               | Emirates Team New Zealand     
UK   |United Kingdom            | INEOS Team UK     
USA  |United States of America  | NYYC American Magic
4 rows

SELECT * FROM races
>
Race    Tournament  Date    Racedate 
RR1R1   RR          15-Jan  18642   
RR1R2   RR          15-Jan  18642   
RR1R3   RR          16-Jan  18643   
RR2R1   RR          16-Jan  18643   
RR2R2   RR          17-Jan  18644   
RR2R3   RR          17-Jan  18644   
RR3R1   RR          23-Jan  18650   
RR3R2   RR          23-Jan  18650   
RR3R3   RR          23-Jan  18650   
SFR1    SF          29-Jan  18656
1-10 of 31 rows

SELECT * FROM tournaments
>
Tournament  Event           TournamentName
RR          Prada Cup       Round Robin     
SF          Prada Cup       Semi-Final      
F           Prada Cup       Final       
AC          America's Cup   Americas Cup
4 rows

SELECT *
FROM results
>
Race   Code    Result
FR1    ITA     Win      
FR1    UK      Loss     
FR2    UK      Loss     
FR2    ITA     Win      
FR3    UK      Loss     
FR3    ITA     Win      
FR4    ITA     Win      
FR4    UK      Loss     
FR5    ITA     Win      
FR5  UK Loss        
1-10 of 62 rows
```

and I'm trying to write an SQL query that will output the number of races each team won by tournament, and show the output. The output table should include the full name of the Event, the Tournament and the full name of each team. My query at the moment looks like this:

```
SELECT TeamName, Result, Event, tournaments.Tournament
FROM teams LEFT JOIN results
ON teams.Code = results.Code
LEFT JOIN races
ON results.Race = races.Race
LEFT JOIN tournaments
ON races.Tournament = tournaments.Tournament
WHERE Result = 'Win'
ORDER BY tournaments.Tournament
```

which outputs:

```
TeamName                        Result  Event           Tournament
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Luna Rossa Prada Pirelli Team   Win     America's Cup   AC  
Luna Rossa Prada Pirelli Team   Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Luna Rossa Prada Pirelli Team   Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC  
Emirates Team New Zealand       Win     America's Cup   AC
```

When I try to `COUNT(Result) AS NumberOfWins`, I get:

```
TeamName                        Result    NumberOfWins    Event     Tournament
Luna Rossa Prada Pirelli Team   Win       31              Prada Cup F
1 row
```

Why does adding the count count only Luna Rossa's wins? How can I change the query to fix it?

Comment: why the [tag:r] tag?

Comment: I'm using SQLite in R. Inappropriate?

Comment: The question is SQL-based, all of your sample data and code are SQL, and you ask how to get it with SQLite. Whether you're accessing the sqlite database via R or python or ruby, it's still a question about SQLite. Keep it, I don't care, perhaps somebody who knows SQL follows [tag:r] and not [tag:sqlite].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does adding the count count only Luna Rossa's wins?

**Count()** is an aggregate function and produces one result per **GROUP**.

As you have no `GROUP BY` clause the entire result set is a single group and hence the single result.

- The reason why you got Tournament F is due to

  - *If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once across the entire dataset. **Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression.** Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.* As per [SQLite SELECT](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) -

> How can I change the query to fix it?

So you need a `GROUP BY` clause. To create groups upon which the count() function will work on.

You probably want **`GROUP BY Tournament,TeamName`**

e.g.

```
SELECT TeamName, Result, Event, tournaments.Tournament, count(*)
FROM teams LEFT JOIN results
ON teams.Code = results.Code
LEFT JOIN races
ON results.Race = races.Race
LEFT JOIN tournaments
ON races.Tournament = tournaments.Tournament
WHERE Result = 'Win'
GROUP BY Tournament,Teamname
ORDER BY tournaments.Tournament
```